# Very confusing adjective in two forms: -ing and -ed

Tags: adjectives, participles

> **6.** The witnesses gave __ *conflicted* __ reports of what happened during the robbery.

The answer key says the right answer is “conflicting reports”.
I agree that it’s easier to read or distinguish from past tense verb “gave” but both “conflicting” and “conflicted” are both adjectives.

I realized as I composed this that the difference is people FEEL “conflicted” and inanimate objects can be a “conflicting” source.....

But, just how significant is this distinction?
Does this apply to ALL -ed, -ing ending adjectives?????

Comment: You haven't really made a statement of what you think the general distinction is, but I doubt you can generalize much from this particular case anyway.

Comment: Yes, people can feel conflicted, but this isn't about feelings. The reports of the different witnesses didn't agree with one another; they were _conflicting_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With participial adjectives in general, the "ing" ones indicate the action of the base verb, while the "ed" ones indicate receiving the action of the verb. A lot of the "ed" ones end up being adjectives describing feelings.

In general, if you have an adjective before a noun, X, and you have to decide which participial adjective to put there, ask yourself, "Does X do the verb?" If yes, the answer is "ing", and otherwise it's "ed".

In this case, "Do the witness reports conflict?" The answer is yes, so "conflicting" is correct.

An "ed" adjective means X *receives the action* of the verb. So if you use "conflicted", it means something else *conflicts* the reports, which isn't what's happening in this story.

Incidentally, the only meaning the adjective "conflicted" has in English is having a conflict of emotions or desires in your own mind. Reports cannot have emotions or desires, so "conflicted" doesn't make sense.